# How to use .replace to delete part of a string (if the part exists on an array)?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have several words I would like to delete from a string (this will be in a for loop):

Most of the words I need to be deleted are ( this is the regex I've tried):

```
\b([[:<:]][0-9a-zA-z][[:>:]]|^'|about|after|all|also|[an]|and|another|any|are|[as]|at|[be]|because|been|before|being|\bbetween|both|but|by|came|can|come|could|did|do|each|for|from|get|got|had|[has]|have|he|her|here|him|himself|his|how|if|in|into|is|it|like|make|many|me|might|more|most|much|must|my|never|now|of|on|only|or|other|our|out|over|said|same|see|should|since|some|still|such|take|than|that|the|their|them|then|there|these|they|this|those|through|to|too|under|up|very|was|way|we|well|were|what|where|which|while|who|with|would|you|your)
```

As you can see I need to delete a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and several words

As an example I have this phrase:

"This is the Stackoverflow's Data and its into many sites"

My expected result would be:

"This is the Stackoverflow's Data and its many sites"

what I've tried is this:

```
   let wordsHidden=["[about]","[after]","[all]","[also]","[an]","[and]","[another]","[any]","[are]","[as]","[at]","[be]","[because]","[been]","[before]","[being]","[between]","[both]","[but]","[by]","[came]","[can]","[come]","[could]","[did]","[do]","[each]","[for]","[from]","[get]","[got]","[had]","[has]","[have]","[he]","[her]","[here]","[him]","[himself]","[his]","[how]","[if]","[in]","[into]","[is]","[it]","[like]","[make]","[many]","[me]","[might]","[more]","[most]","[much]","[must]","[my]","[never]","[now]","[of]","[on]","[only]","[or]","[other]","[our]","[out]","[over]","[said]","[same]","[see]","[should]","[since]","[some]","[still]","[such]","[take]","[than]","[that]","[the]","[their]","[them]","[then]","[there]","[these]","[they]","[this]","[those]","[through]","[to]","[too]","[under]","[up]","[very]","[was]","[way]","[we]","[well]","[were]","[what]","[where]","[which]","[while]","[who]","[with]","[would]","[you]","[your]"];

   let test = wordsHidden.join("|");

  let regexorg = "/\b([[:<:]][0-9a-zA-z][[:>:]]|^'|"+test+")";
  var regex = new RegExp("/"+wordsHidden.join("|")+"/", 'g');

  let string = "DLs between data";
  console.log(string.replace(regex,''));
```

This is the regex on action
[image]

is there any way to treat every part of the array as a whole word and return the whole processed word?

Comment: Can you share the link to your regex playground instead of posting a screenshot? Being able to work with your data directly is helpful. In your second regex, putting all of the words you want matched inside of `[]`s is probably not what you want--order ceases to matter and it's just matching any single character from the group. `foo|bar` is what you want, not `[foo]|[bar]`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `[[:<:]][0-9a-zA-z][[:>:]]`?

Comment: [[:<:]][0-9a-zA-z][[:>:]] this is to select only single characters ( 0 to 9, a to z and A to Z) so for example if I have this text: "Theres a hope" it should be "Theres hope"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the start of your rex, but I have figured out a way to delete specific strings (wrapped with a non-word character) from a string.

If you JUST match the exact strings you will be left with extra spaces, so my approach is to match a non-word character on either side of each word, matching each continuing word it finds that is in the list. If we DON'T chain words like this we won't catch adjacent words (since each one will try to match the non-word characters around itself and those will collide, and we will miss adjacent matches)

```
wordsHidden=["about","after","all","also","an","and","another","any","are","as","at","be","because","been","before","being","between","both","but","by","came","can","come","could","did","do","each","for","from","get","got","had","has","have","he","her","here","him","himself","his","how","if","in","into","is","it","like","make","many","me","might","more","most","much","must","my","never","now","of","on","only","or","other","our","out","over","said","same","see","should","since","some","still","such","take","than","that","the","their","them","then","there","these","they","this","those","through","to","too","under","up","very","was","way","we","well","were","what","where","which","while","who","with","would","you","your"];
rexString = "\\W((" + wordsHidden.join("\\W)|(") + "\\W))+";
console.log(rexString);
regex = new RegExp(rexString, 'g');

string = "This is the Stackoverflow's Data and its into many your your you your about you sites";
match = regex.exec(string);
matches = [];
while (match != null) {
  match.lastIndex = regex.lastIndex;
  matches.push(match);
  match = regex.exec(string);
}

cutString = string;
// iterate through matches backwards from end of string to start,
// so we don't shift our indexes as we delete parts of the string)
for (i = matches.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  match = matches[i];
  beforeMatch = cutString.substr(0, match.lastIndex - match[0].length);
  afterMatch = cutString.substr(match.lastIndex - 1); //leave the trailing "space", might be some other character
  console.log(beforeMatch); console.log(match[0]); console.log(afterMatch);
  cutString = beforeMatch + afterMatch;
}
console.log(cutString);
```

```
This goes from
"This is the Stackoverflow's Data and its into many your your you your about you sites" to
"This Stackoverflow's Data its sites"
with all the matching words stripped (is, the, and, into, many, your, you, about)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite `wordsHidden` to not include the `[]` around each word, otherwise it will just match a single character that occurs in one of the words in the array. Then you need to check for any of the words (or a single digit/character) within word boundaries, noting that we don't want to delete a single character if it occurs after a `'`:

```js
let wordsHidden=["about","after","all","also","an","and","another","any","are","as","at","be","because","been","before","being","between","both","but","by","came","can","come","could","did","do","each","for","from","get","got","had","has","have","he","her","here","him","himself","his","how","if","in","into","is","it","like","make","many","me","might","more","most","much","must","my","never","now","of","on","only","or","other","our","out","over","said","same","see","should","since","some","still","such","take","than","that","the","their","them","then","there","these","they","this","those","through","to","too","under","up","very","was","way","we","well","were","what","where","which","while","who","with","would","you","your"];
let regex = new RegExp("\\b([^'][0-9a-z]|" + wordsHidden.join('|') + ')\\b', 'gi');

string = "This is the Stackoverflow's Data and its many sites";
console.log(string.replace(regex, ''));
```